# Can I toggle fringe-mode when entering / exiting emacs edebug?

Tags: emacs

For the most part I prefer to disable Emacs' fringe with `fringe-mode` `no-fringes`.  But I like to have the left fringe active when debugging elisp code (for the little fringe arrow pointing to the active line).

I found `edebug-setup-hook` for setting `fringe-mode` to `left-only` when entering edebug, but I'm fairly certain that's not what that hook is for.  (Basing that on the fact that Emacs resets `edebug-setup-hook` to nil all the time.)

Is there a way to set `fringe-mode` back to `no-fringes` upon exiting the debugger?  Is there a better way to set it to `left-only` upon entering?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you are asking for:

```
(add-hook 'edebug-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-fringe-mode
             (set (make-local-variable 'fringe-mode)
                  (if edebug-mode '(nil . 0) 0)))))
```

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using?  I've got 24.3.1, and mine doesn't have `edebug-mode` or an `edebug-mode-hook`.

Comment: Emacs 24.3 ***does*** have `edebug-mode`, but you have to first load library `edebug.el` to then see it using `C-h f`. Each mode is defined to use a mode hook variable, if one is referenced (e.g., by `add-hook`). IOW, the variable does not need to preexist --- this is true of modes in general.

Comment: Coming back to this question more than a year too late, my apologies.  The code as given did not work, I think because edebug is implemented as a recursive edit, not a true minor mode.  Mind if I move to the new emacs.SE?

Comment: I certainly don't mind. Hope you find what you are looking for. Wrt the code above, you might want to say what "did not work" amounts to.